# unable to use the img tag in node JS unless i use any other tag before it

Tags: node.js, express

so im new to node js, when i try to use the img tag like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');

const app=express();



app.get("/",function(req,res){
  const url="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Aleppo&appid=2039d73e06ccce302ec637c639416236&units=metric"
  https.get(url,function(response){
    response.on("data",function(data){
      const sdata=JSON.parse(data);
      const weatherDes=sdata.weather[0].description;
      //res.write("<h1>It is  "+weatherDes+" today </h1>");
      const icon=sdata.weather[0].icon;
      const imgUrl="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/"+ icon + "@2x.png";
      res.write("<img src=" + imgUrl + ">");
      res.send();

    });
});

});




app.listen(3000,function(req,res){
  console.log("up and runing!")
});
```

it doesnt work untill i remove the "//" in the res.write before it, i just want to know why this is happening.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean exactly?

Comment: it only shows this in the browser "<img src=http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/01d@2x.png>" and doesn't show an img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send multiple images like this

```
res.send(`<img src=${imgUrl}><img src=${imgUrl}><img src=${imgUrl}><img src=${imgUrl}>`)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
res.write("<img src=" + imgUrl + ">");
res.send();
```

Change this to

```
res.send("<img src=" + imgUrl + ">");
```

Happy Coding

Comment: it does work, but i want to use the res.write method since i can send multiple things to the web page , however the <img> tag doesn't work on its own like other html tags , i just want to know the reason behind it.

Comment: I Posted a new answer try that :)